# notation : $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ instead of $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, notation, density-function

I just have a notation question. The density $f_{X|Y}(\cdot, y)$ is defined by $$\mathbb{P}(X\in A|Y=y)=:\int_A f_{X|Y}(x|y)dx$$ would the notation $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ instead of $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ also be reasonable? I only see the first notation used.

Comment: It is reasonable to use such a notation. The main advantage is that it is compatible with the notation $f_{X|A}(x)$ for the conditional density of $X$ given an event $A$, and it has been used by some authors. One drawback is that the expression $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ is less compact compared to $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$, especially when one wants to omit function arguments.

Comment: @SangchulLee, thank you. But if we omit the arguments we are left with $f_{X|Y}$ and so the density is not fully defined since we don't know on which particular value of $y$ we condition right? So we would need to write $f_{X|Y}(\cdot| y)$ which is not more compact

Comment: You can treat $f_{X|Y}$ as a function of two arguments, namely $(x, y) \mapsto f_{X|Y}(x|y)$. So, not knowing the particular value of $y$ is not a big issue here. This viewpoint is sometimes useful, especially when on would like to regard $f_{X|Y}$ as a transition kernel.

Comment: @SangchulLee, okay I understand now.